# Get WIFI ID from last connected WIFI

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I'm writing an Android application which should react if the phone connects or disconnects to a WIFI network. I registered a `BroadcastReceiver` for this and it works great. Now with this code I'm able to get the current WIFI ID if the phone is connected to a WIFI:

```
WifiManager mainWifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo currentWifi = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();

int id = currentWifi.getNetworkId();
```

But what if the WIFI disconnects and I want to get the WIFI ID of the last connected WIFI? My problem is that all this is in an `BroadcastReceiver`. This is allways new created if a new Broadcast comes in so I can not really save some data there. Is there a method or something else with which I can get the last connected WIFI ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm missing something. You could [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to have a context to access from Broadcast receiver.

*This BroadcastReceiver intercepts the android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, which indicates a connection change. It checks whether the type is TYPE_WIFI. If it is, it checks whether Wi-Fi is connected and sets the wifiConnected flag in the main activity accordingly.*

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // Checks the user prefs and the network connection. Based on the result, decides
        // whether
        // to refresh the display or keep the current display.
        // If the userpref is Wi-Fi only, checks to see if the device has a Wi-Fi connection.
        if (WIFI.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null
                && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // If device has its Wi-Fi connection, sets refreshDisplay
            // to true. This causes the display to be refreshed when the user
            // returns to the app.
```

You can find here the [sample app](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NetworkUsage.zip).